# Postman (getpostman.com) - nested array

Tags: php, postman

I'm not sure if anything has changed, but I'm sure, it was possible to pass an array like this:

[image]

This request would end up in array (php):

```
[
   'title' => 'Article',
   'author' => [
      'first_name' => 'John',
      'last_name' => 'Doe'
   ]
]
```

But if I try send this request now, it is no more possible and sends request like this:

```
[
   'title' => 'Article',
   'author[first_name]' => 'John',
   'author[last_name]' => 'Doe'
]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve sending nested array?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can send a nested array here, because it contains `key` : `value` here

Comment: @MayankPandeyz as I said, it was working, but it doesn't anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass things like that it will end up as strings on your server. If you are actually trying to pass nested/associative data you can change your body to `raw` and select JSON as the `content-type`.

```
{
    "title" : "Article",
    "author": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name" : "Doe"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that, thank you. But I'm 100% sure it was possible as I mentioned. This is a backup solution.

Comment: Are you sure your server side code was not parsing the string into an php array? If you think it is a bug in Postman you can discuss it in the Postman Community Slack channel - https://www.getpostman.com/slack-invite

Comment: I don't know, will try. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, for anybody coming across this answer years later like I did: **Postman does not like single-quotes around JSON variable names, only double-quotes!**